# Rendering Angular JS partials views with ASP.NET Development Server

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm currently trying to use Visual Studio 2010 to learn some Angular JS and I'm having a problem rendering partials views.  I have a shell page `index.html` and a table which contains some person data inside `/partials/list.html`.  When a user clicks on a button located in the table in `list.html` they should be taken to another partial view `edit.html`.  When I run the project the I get this as the url in the browser: `http://localhost:62807/index.html#/`
and the partial view `list.html` is injected where it needs to be.  Here's what those two things look like:

```
index.html

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular JS Routing</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css"
              rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-app="enterprise" ng-controller="AppController">
        <a href="#"><h2>Enterprise Crew</h2></a>
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

here's the partial view injected into the ng-view tag from index.html

```
<table class="table table-striped" style="width: 250px">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td> <a href="/new"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i></a>

        </td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in crew">
        <td>{{person.name}}</td>
        <td>{{person.description}}</td>
        <td><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's what it looks like when it's rendered:
[image]

When the user clicks the plus sign they need to be taken to another partial view `edit.html`, this is in the same partials folder as list.html. It's HTML looks like

edit.html

```
<form action="">
    <input ng-model="person.name"/>
    <input ng-model="person.description"/>
    <button ng-click="save()" class="btn-primary">Save</button>
    save function not yet implemented
</form>
```

When I'm at the URL in my browser `http://localhost:62807/index.html#/` everything loads up fine and the list.html partial view is injected where it needs to be.  When I hover my mouse over the plus button I get a URL preview of `localhost:62807/new`.  When clicked this should inject the edit.html partial view, but instead I get a 404 error.

Here's the JS.

```
angular.module('enterprise',['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when("/",{templateUrl:"partials/list.html"})
            .when("/new",{templateUrl:"/partials/edit.html"})
    })
//this is the that iterated over in the partial views ng-repeat
function AppController($scope){
    $scope.crew =[
        {name:'Picard',description:'captain'},
        {name: 'Riker',description:'number 1'},
        {name:'Word',description:'Security'}
    ]
}
```

The problem is somewhere in the routing, I believe.  In video tutorials I have followed I notice that the URLs that I get when I run the application include either the project name or the page name in them (in this case index.html is included in the URL).  I'm curious why the `list.html` view gets injected correctly in the first place, and whenever I try to navigate to `/new` the edit.html partial view isn't correctly injected.  I'm playing around with this all locally, so I would like to first of all get it working and then understand what the deal is and why the list.html partial view will render and edit.html doesn't.

Comment: Is the leading `/` intentional in your `"/new"` route templateUrl **"/partials/edit.html"** ?

Comment: @YanikCeulemans yes, from the example I followed, but mine doesn't work so..maybe not? :).  So `localhost:5555` should render index.html with list.html inside of it, and then navigating to /new from the root directory should inject edit.html where list.html was.

Comment: Well, the leading slash would cause the partial not to be found if the partials directory isn't located in the root directory of the website

Comment: Duly noted, thanks.  It was in this case, but good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the url should be

`<a href="#/new"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i></a>`

Comment: That was it.  Thanks so much, this was a pain.  This has something to do with html5Mode, right?  Can you explain why this works?

Comment: The html5 mode is not in use. If you enable it then on mew browser you can use `/new`. This is supported by old browsers.